# Creating a 2D game with modern opengl

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

I've tried for some time to create a simple 2D Engine with modern opengl, with modern opengl I mean I'm not going to be using this:

```
glBegin(); glEnd(); glVertex2i(); glOrtho();
```

etc, 
I'm using GLSL.

And I have run into some problems. Here's some questions

- I'm trying to create a 2D coordinate system without using old methods like glOrtho() and glViewport(), I know i'm supposed to use a matrix here and there but how? How do i create a coordinate system?
- How do I use texCoords in GLSL to load a texture in 2D space.
- If someone could explain or point to a source on how to set the size of a Texture, right now I've to use a position from -1 to 1, but I want to say that the size is 16 * 16 for example.
- Is there someway to print out errors from GLSL? When I have an error it's just prints out Couldn't find uniform. Because the location is == -1
- How to use and create matrix to to move, scale and rotate in **2D** space.
- Can I use a Matrix2f instead of Matrix4f?

Please, if you can, post the code in **Java** Thank you

Comment: glViewport is not deprecated and must be used also in modern OpenGL. In fact it's important you call it so that OpenGL knows, how to map NDC coordinates to window coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't have much experience with modern OpenGL but I worked with recent DirectX'es. Most of general conceptions should be the same here.

> How do i create a coordinate system?

Nowadays there is no fixed function pipeline so one have to do all coordinate transformations by hand inside a vertex shader. It consumes a vertex then produces one transformed to the screen space. In case of 2D graphics there's even no need to bother with projection matrices.

Consider the input stream consisting from 2D vectors. Thus rotation, scaling and translation implemented with 3D matrices. But output vectors should be 4D. Pseudocode:

```
input = getInputVertex();
transformed = view * world * vec3(input, 1.0f);
output = vec4(transformed, 1.0f);
```

Where 'world' is a world matrix of sprite and 'view' is a matrix of camera.